# How should I write 30 000 user data containing base64 photos to the API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a post method in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 project and it writes the incoming user data to the database.

The incoming data is sent once a day and contains data of 30 000 people. This information includes 4-5 small pieces of information (such as name, surname) and a photo converted to base64 format.

When I post this data to my API, I get a 502 error. My project does not crash, it is still standing, and nothing appears in the log. What could be causing this problem? Or is there an alternative, better way to accept such data?

I both write the data to the database and convert the base64 photo to file and save it to the server.

The model format I accept is as follows:

```
{
   employees:[
     {
        "name": "Smith",
        "surname": "Smith",
        "email": "smith@gmail.com",
        "phone": "9435353445",
        "status": true,
        "photo": base64 photo
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Base64 is inappropriate for binary content exceeding more than a couple of kilobytes. I would redesign that API so that `"photo":` accepts either a URI or a content-addressable-storage address (i.e. a SHA-256 hash of the photo) then provide the photo images in separate requests as raw binary content.

Answer (score -3):

you are likely being blocked by the size of the data that is accepted, they do this to protect you from getting flooded by a hacker taking your server offline.

Give this a try:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```